# How to show marker with text in map in codenameone

Tags: google-maps, codenameone

I am doing a sample on Map and in this i want to show marker along with text.

for that i used below code.

```
MapContainer mapContainer = new MapContainer("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
Coord coord = new Coord(latitude,longitude);
mapContainer.setCameraPosition(coord);
mapContainer.addMarker(EncodedImage.createFromImage(image,false), mapContainer.getCameraPosition(), "Text", "Text", null);
```

but this code helps me to displaying the marker but not along with the text. so if anyone have idea to display marker with text please suggest/help me to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

here is the code using MapContainer and MapLayout(Below Answer)..

```
if(BrowserComponent.isNativeBrowserSupported()) {
        MapContainer mc = new MapContainer("AIzaSyDLIu4RfdXVQPvRqOYLP6N8ocCQpPNqtIk");
        mapDemo.add(mc);
        Container markers = new Container();
        markers.setLayout(new MapLayout(mc, markers));
        mapDemo.add(markers);

        Coord moscone = new Coord(37.7831, -122.401558);
        Button mosconeButton = new Button("");
        FontImage.setMaterialIcon(mosconeButton, FontImage.MATERIAL_PLACE);
        markers.add(moscone, mosconeButton);

        Coord moscone1 = new Coord(36.6139, -120.2090);
        Button mosconeButton1 = new Button("");
        FontImage.setMaterialIcon(mosconeButton1, FontImage.MATERIAL_PLACE);
        markers.add(moscone1, mosconeButton1);

        mc.zoom(moscone1, 5);
    } else {
        // iOS Screenshot process...
        mapDemo.add(new Label("Loading, please wait...."));
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This is a revised answer see the original answer for reference below:

With the new update this should work better, you will need to update the cn1lib for Google Maps too if you have an older version. We've also revised the `MapLayout` class again and added some features such as alignment:

```
public class MapLayout extends Layout implements MapListener {
        private static final String COORD_KEY = "$coord";
        private static final String POINT_KEY = "$point";
        private static final String HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT = "$align";
        private static final String VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT = "$valign";
        private final MapContainer map;
        private final Container actual;
        private boolean inUpdate;
        private Runnable nextUpdate;        
        private int updateCounter;

        public static enum HALIGN {
            LEFT {
                @Override
                int convert(int x, int width) {
                    return x;
                }
            },
            CENTER {
                @Override
                int convert(int x, int width) {
                    return x - width / 2;
                }
            }, 
            RIGHT {
                @Override
                int convert(int x, int width) {
                    return x - width;
                }
            };

            abstract int convert(int x, int width);
        }

        public static enum VALIGN {
            TOP {
                @Override
                int convert(int y, int height) {
                    return y;
                }
            }, 
            MIDDLE {
                @Override
                int convert(int y, int height) {
                    return y + height / 2;
                }
            }, 
            BOTTOM {
                @Override
                int convert(int y, int height) {
                    return y + height;
                }
            };

            abstract int convert(int y, int height);
        }

        public MapLayout(MapContainer map, Container actual) {
            this.map = map;
            this.actual = actual;
            map.addMapListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void addLayoutComponent(Object value, Component comp, Container c) {
            comp.putClientProperty(COORD_KEY, (Coord) value);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isConstraintTracking() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getComponentConstraint(Component comp) {
            return comp.getClientProperty(COORD_KEY);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isOverlapSupported() {
            return true;
        }

        public static void setHorizontalAlignment(Component cmp, HALIGN a) {
            cmp.putClientProperty(HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT, a);
        }

        public static void setVerticalAlignment(Component cmp, VALIGN a) {
            cmp.putClientProperty(VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT, a);
        }

        @Override
        public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
            int parentX = 0;
            int parentY = 0;
            for (Component current : parent) {
                Coord crd = (Coord) current.getClientProperty(COORD_KEY);
                Point p = (Point) current.getClientProperty(POINT_KEY);
                if (p == null) {
                    p = map.getScreenCoordinate(crd);
                    current.putClientProperty(POINT_KEY, p);
                }
                HALIGN h = (HALIGN)current.getClientProperty(HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT);
                if(h == null) {
                    h = HALIGN.LEFT;
                }
                VALIGN v = (VALIGN)current.getClientProperty(VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT);
                if(v == null) {
                    v = VALIGN.TOP;
                }
                current.setSize(current.getPreferredSize());
                current.setX(h.convert(p.getX() - parentX, current.getWidth()));
                current.setY(v.convert(p.getY() - parentY, current.getHeight()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize(Container parent) {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }

        @Override
        public void mapPositionUpdated(Component source, int zoom, Coord center) {
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    inUpdate = true;
                    try {
                        List<Coord> coords = new ArrayList<>();
                        List<Component> cmps = new ArrayList<>();
                        int len = actual.getComponentCount();
                        for (Component current : actual) {
                            Coord crd = (Coord) current.getClientProperty(COORD_KEY);
                            coords.add(crd);
                            cmps.add(current);
                        }
                        int startingUpdateCounter = ++updateCounter;
                        List<Point> points = map.getScreenCoordinates(coords);
                        if (startingUpdateCounter != updateCounter || len != points.size()) {
                            // Another update must have run while we were waiting for the bounding box.
                            // in which case, that update would be more recent than this one.
                            return;
                        }
                        for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
                            Component current = cmps.get(i);
                            Point p = points.get(i);
                            current.putClientProperty(POINT_KEY, p);
                        }
                        actual.setShouldCalcPreferredSize(true);
                        actual.revalidate();
                        if (nextUpdate != null) {
                            Runnable nex = nextUpdate;
                            nextUpdate = null;
                            callSerially(nex);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        inUpdate = false;
                    }

                }

            };
            if (inUpdate) {
                nextUpdate = r;
            } else {
                nextUpdate = null;
                callSerially(r);
            }           
        }
}
```

**Original Answer:**

The marker will show the text when you tap on it. If you want things to appear differently you can just use any component and place it on top of the map. The upcoming [Uber tutorial](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/uber.html) will cover this in depth but I explained the basic system in this blog post: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-map-layout-manager.html

Comment: its working but if i add multiple markers while zooming (in/out) some times markers overlapping each other and getting stackoverflow error also.. and lts happening in only devices in simulator its working fine..

Comment: They will overlap if there are a lot of markers. You can use the map listener to add/remove markers and create the effect of unifying markers. We might want to create a more standardized layout API moving forward that will deal with all of these issues. If you see an exception try to inspect the device printouts using a USB cable and see the root of the stack overflow.

Comment: if more than one marker added to maps, when the map moves/zoom markers are not stable and markers showing in same location and its keep on blinking.

Comment: On which device/OS version. Are you sure the native map is active and not the JavaScript fallback?

Comment: i'm not sure its native or not but its happening in all versions(tested in 3 versions like 4.4,5.0 and 7.0) in android..

Comment: The native map falls back to a JavaScript implementation if it's misconfigured. Try generating a clear video and a simple test case that reproduces this

Comment: sorry for late shai.. here is the video link https://www.dropbox.com/s/nijygtw0mqvr52q/VID-20171229-WA0015.mp4?dl=0.. in this video i'm just doing zoom in/out and drag the map..

Comment: Steve did some editing to the map layout code which might impact this see https://gist.github.com/shannah/2fa0a6ba22ee9baecb8fc384d9bba5ed do you see any exceptions in the device when you connect a cable and look through the printouts?

Comment: Thanks Shai and Steve.. i tried latest Map layout now its working better but still overlapping is there..
and Markers are  not showing at exact position(see both markers,it showing in different locations).. here is the video link https://www.dropbox.com/s/64zrhyqvke0elzn/20171230.mp4?dl=0..

Comment: Notice that component X/Y is in the top left location and you might want the bottom center of the marker to point at the spot. I'm thinking about enhancing the layout to support more elaborate icon positions. As I mentioned before the overlapping will exist inherently you will need to control the components within based on map zoom/density.

Comment: sorry shai.. i didn't get it can you please elaborate it little bit more.. Thanks..

Comment: Overlapping is something that will naturally happen as you zoom out and points become closer together. We might add an API to simplify that in the future. The flickering issue is something I see too, I'm looking into this. It might require an update to both the map layout and the google maps cn1lib

Comment: Ok shai.. once you fixed these issues let me know then i will update lib and maplayout.. Thanks for your support shai..

Comment: We have a fix for this that should go in over the weekend. It will require a newer version of the map layout code

Comment: Thanks shai.. and Sorry for late reply.. i tried the revised answer but still marker is not placing in the correct position.. i tried to place the markers in India but initially it showing outside the India after zooming also you can observe that Agra is showing some down in the map which is not exact location of Agra..  here is the video https://www.dropbox.com/s/sbh69ett7ohtv3f/20180109_174148_edited%5B1%5D.mp4?dl=0.. please check it.. Thanks..

Comment: Is this reproducible in the simulator now or only on devices? We made some changes to the simulator that should make it more consistent assuming you use the JavaScript version and not the MapCompoent version.

Comment: Its reproducible in simulator and devices also.. but when compare to simulator in devices we can identity the issue correctly..

Comment: If you are seeing this in the simulator this isn't the `MapComponent` version. Can you please file an issue with a test case http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/ this is getting a bit long and might get lost if there isn't an issue to track it